# How to properly simplify seemingly unnecessary parts in Z3?

Tags: python-3.x, z3, smt

Once applied a sequence of tactics to some constraint (copied below), Z3 gives the following output:

```
(goals
(goal
  (or (<= b a) k!0)
  (or (not (>= a 10)) (not (<= b a)) (not k!0))
  k!1
  k!2
  (or (not (>= a 0)) k!0)
  (= a 10)
  (>= b 5)
  (<= b 15)
  :precision precise :depth 9)
(goal
  k!0
  (or (<= b a) k!0)
  (or (not (>= a 10)) (not (<= b a)) (not k!0))
  k!1
  k!2
  (or (not (>= a 0)) k!0)
  (>= a 1)
  (<= a 10)
  (>= b 5)
  (<= b 15)
  :precision precise :depth 9)
)
```

k!0, k!1 and k!2 are apparently true. Is there a way to eliminate them?

This is the closest question I could find. [Simplifying uninterpreted functions in Z3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15347244/simplifying-uninterpreted-functions-in-z3)

Below SMT code can be used at https://compsys-tools.ens-lyon.fr/z3/index.php for a quick reproduction

```
; Variable declarations
(declare-fun a () Int)
(declare-fun b () Int)
(declare-fun c () Int)

; Constraint
(assert (not (and (>= a 0) 
                  (or (and (not (<= a 10)) (<= b a)) 
                      (and (not (<= a 10)) (not (<= a b))) 
                      (and (>= a 10) (<= b a)) ))))

(assert (and (>= a 1) (<= a 10) (>= b 5) (<= b 15)))

(apply (then (! simplify :elim-and true) elim-term-ite tseitin-cnf simplify propagate-values (par-then split-clause propagate-ineqs) simplify ctx-simplify))
```

Comment: I doubt you can. Tactics are very fragile, and whether they kick in or not and under what circumstances depends on the precise z3 version. I found them almost impossible to use reliably, aside from big-hammers like `sat`/`smt` and quantifier-elimination ones. Best of luck!

Comment: Thank you for the comment @alias. Then I will stop searching for a solution and keep them as they are.